# C++ file input/output search

Tags: visual-c++, search, file-io

Hi I took the following code from a program I'm writing to check a user generated string against a dictionary as well as other validation.

My problem is that although my dictionary file is referenced correctly,the program gives the default "no dictionary found".I can't see clearly what I'm doing in error here,if anyone has any tips or pointers it would be appreciated,

Thanks.

```
        //variables for checkWordInFile

        #define gC_FOUND 99
        #define gC_NOT_FOUND -99





        //
        static bool certifyThat(bool condition, const char* error) {
            if(!condition) printf("%s", error);
            return !condition;
        }

        //method to validate a user generated password following password guidelines.
        void validatePass()
        {
            FILE *fptr;
            char password[MAX+1];
            int iChar,iUpper,iLower,iSymbol,iNumber,iTotal,iResult,iCount;



            //shows user password guidelines
            printf("\n\n\t\tPassword rules: ");
            printf("\n\n\t\t 1. Passwords must be at least 9 characters long and less than 15 characters. ");
            printf("\n\n\t\t 2. Passwords must have at least 2 numbers in them.");
            printf("\n\n\t\t 3. Passwords must have at least 2 uppercase letters and 2 lowercase letters in them.");
            printf("\n\n\t\t 4. Passwords must have at least 1 symbol in them (eg ?, $, £, %).");
            printf("\n\n\t\t 5. Passwords may not have small, common words in them eg hat, pow or ate.");

            //gets user password input
            get_user_password:

            printf("\n\n\t\tEnter your password following password rules: ");
            scanf("%s", &password);


            iChar = countLetters(password,&iUpper,&iLower,&iSymbol,&iNumber,&iTotal);
            iUpper = countLetters(password,&iUpper,&iLower,&iSymbol,&iNumber,&iTotal);
            iLower =countLetters(password,&iUpper,&iLower,&iSymbol,&iNumber,&iTotal);
            iSymbol =countLetters(password,&iUpper,&iLower,&iSymbol,&iNumber,&iTotal);
            iNumber = countLetters(password,&iUpper,&iLower,&iSymbol,&iNumber,&iTotal);
            iTotal = countLetters(password,&iUpper,&iLower,&iSymbol,&iNumber,&iTotal);



            if(certifyThat(iUpper >= 2, "Not enough uppercase letters!!!\n")
             || certifyThat(iLower >= 2, "Not enough lowercase letters!!!\n")
             || certifyThat(iSymbol >= 1, "Not enough symbols!!!\n")
             || certifyThat(iNumber >= 2, "Not enough numbers!!!\n")
             || certifyThat(iTotal >= 9, "Not enough characters!!!\n")
             || certifyThat(iTotal <= 15, "Too many characters!!!\n"))

            goto get_user_password;

            iResult = checkWordInFile("dictionary.txt", password);

            if(certifyThat(iResult != gC_FOUND, "Password contains small common 3 letter word/s."))
            goto get_user_password;

            iResult = checkWordInFile("passHistory.txt",password);

            if(certifyThat(iResult != gC_FOUND, "Password contains previously used password."))
            goto get_user_password;


            printf("\n\n\n Your new password is verified ");
            printf(password);

            //writing password to passHistroy file.


            fptr = fopen("passHistory.txt", "w");   // create or open the file
            for( iCount = 0; iCount < 8; iCount++)
            {
                fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", password[iCount]);
            }

            fclose(fptr);


            printf("\n\n\n");
            system("pause");


        }//end validatePass method

        int checkWordInFile(char * fileName,char * theWord){

            FILE * fptr;
            char fileString[MAX + 1];
            int iFound = -99;
            //open the file
            fptr = fopen(fileName, "r");
            if (fptr == NULL)
            {
                printf("\nNo dictionary file\n");
                printf("\n\n\n");
                system("pause");
                return (0); // just exit the program
            }

            /* read the contents of the file */
            while( fgets(fileString, MAX, fptr) )
            {
                if( 0 == strcmp(theWord, fileString) )
                {
                    iFound = -99;
                }
            }

            fclose(fptr);

            return(0);



        }//end of checkwORDiNFile
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code in your debugger ?

Comment: The following didn't work as it was a problem with strcmp which should have been strncmp,but when I changed to strncmp but I still get the same error,any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use strNcmp, this allows for the length of the word being searched for.  Problem arises with the empty space in the buffer using strcmp,which is what called the default error message.

Answer (score 1):

You need the full path to the file in in the `fopen()` call.

By default Visual Studio makes the working directory to where the solution file is stored, which is not necessarily where the .exe is.

You can change the Working Directory in the project properties to `$(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\` then no path is needed.